# Jqgrid Footer Data appears under scroll using shrinkToFit

Tags: scroll, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid 4.6.0, my problem is that I need to use FooterData, but I have too much columns,so that I have to use shrinkToFit:false, but in this case the Footer Data appears under the scroll

Answer (score 1):

The feature is by design so. You can change the value of `height` option to some small enough value to understand the reason of such behavior. You will see the grid close to the following

[image]

You can see that the grid have tree separate dives:

- header div (hdiv). It contains `<table>` with `<thead>` and all headers of the grid. If one uses `filterToolbar` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention)) or `setGroupHeaders` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar)), then the table contains more as one row with `<th>` elements.
- body div (bdiv) with the the main contains of the grid. It includes `<table>` with `<tbody>` and the rows (`<tr>` elements) with the data.
- footer/summary div (sdiv) with one more separate `<table>` which `<tbody>` contains the data of the footer.

The body div have `scroll` handler, which will be called on scrolling of bdiv. jqGrid set horizontal position (`scrollLeft`) of hdiv and sdiv to the same value which have bdiv. As the result the user can scroll the body div and the horizontal position of hdiv and sdiv stay synchronous to the body div. On the other side **vertical scrolling** of bdiv can be done **separately** and hdiv and sdiv stay fixed.